# Как зафиксировать яндекс карту при редактировании полигона?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Задача - полностью зафиксировать (заморозить) карту при редактировании полигона.
Частично работает следующее:

```
myMap.controls.remove('zoomControl');
myMap.behaviors.disable(['drag', 'scrollZoom', 'dblClickZoom', 'multiTouch', 'rightMouseButtonMagnifier']);
curObject.options.set('editorUseAutoPanInDrawing', false);
```

Проблема: если захватить мышкой одну из точек полигона и подвести ее к краю карты, либо просто переместить весь полигон за пределы карты - карта сдвинется. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Похоже такой функциональности нет. Напишите в техподдержку и попросите Яндекс реализовать это, может они пойдут навстречу.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте у geometryEditor.Polygon отключить опцию useAutoPanInDrawing